# Are the Java Servlet APIs backwards compatible?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to write a JAR file that makes use of the javax servlet API. If I write against version 2.2, does that mean it will work on versions 2.3, 2.4 and 2.5?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldnt they ? The interfaces renamed the same, very few methods got added here and there... If there was a major change in behaviour it wouldnt make sense to reuse the same Interfaces - would it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they are backwards compatible.

[Oracle Source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beagj/index.html)

Comment: Not nessecarily - some things have been deprecated.  Also, some things have their uses clarified in further versions of the servlet spec - for example, SingleThreadModel should be avoided at all costs - if you're ultimately executing your servlets on a 2.3+ compatibile container, you should avoid SingleThreadModel (it is a bad practice, anyways).

Comment: @MetroidFan2002 Your example of [`SingleThreadModel`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) is good one: it became officially deprecated in Servlet 2.4 spec.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, there shouldn't be any compatibility issues. There may be a couple of gotchas, depending on what you are doing. If you are writing some framework that decorates container classes, the interfaces have occasionally been modified. For example, the method [ServletRequest.getRemotePort()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemotePort()) was not present in the [J2EE 1.3 version](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) (before Servlet 2.4). These difficulties can be overcome, but be aware that you're going to have to factor them into your development and testing.

Comment: Thank you.

I noticed one thing - in 2.2 you need to use:
    HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request).toString();

Where as in 2.3+ you can do:
    request.getRequestURL().toString();

Answer (score 1):

It will work, though sometimes some methods will be deprecated and might throw up warnings regarding their implementation.