# maven provided scope and version

Tags: maven, dependencies, version

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I use that dependency import at my project's pom.xml. My question is I declared 2.5 as version. However does it important to write a lower version? For example I mean that if my project uses 3.0 version and I write that 2.5 will be provided? (I mean that let's accept that 2.5 is fine and my project works well, If I don't change anything else and just change 2.5 to 2.0 does it cause to an error?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends.

Generally speaking, if you are expecting an exact version (even if provided) then that is what you should provide.

However, there are instances when you may need to finesse the versions a little. That being said - I would contend 2 points:

1) It is probably ok to have your project expect a lower version and be provided with a higher version; **so long as the higher version is not a major one**. I would suggest taking a look at a good open source versioning model, such as an [Apache project](http://apr.apache.org/versioning.html).

2) It is probably **NOT** ok to have your project expect a higher version and get a lower one. The main reason being that you can't expect things that may not be there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that if I don't use some methods of doesn't have a compatibility with lower versions of it, its OK.

Answer (score 30):

The right solution is to declare the exact servlet api version used in the container to the minor.

The keyword is **provided**: whatever version you specify is used at compile time and for testing. At runtime it is assumed to be provided by your runtime container, e.g. Jetty.

If the actual runtime library differs from the declaration in your POM, you're inviting trouble. Whether you will or won't experience issues is a question of compatibility between the versions.

The Servlet API is backwards compatible, see: 
[Are the Java Servlet APIs backwards compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860938/are-the-java-servlet-apis-backwards-compatible)

Comment: Thanks, you described it well, I'm voting up.